# how to do parallax scrolling in fragments?

Tags: android

I want to use parallax scrolling in fragments in my app. 
I searched regarding this and i got this [link](http://slothdevelopers.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/image-slider-with-parallax-effect-flickr-like/) and i did parallax scrolling in images, now i want to do this for fragments.

Earlier I tried to show fragments in viewpager I did that also by using the code that i mentioned below.
I tried and searched alot regarding parallax in fragments
but I haven't found anything, can anyone help please?

```
public class Dia3 extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog2);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch (pos) {

            case 0:
                return Fragment1.newInstance("");

            case 1:
                return Fragment2.newInstance("");
            case 2:
                return Fragment3.newInstance("");
            case 3:
                return Fragment4.newInstance("");
            case 4:
                return Fragment5.newInstance("");
            default:
                return Fragment1.newInstance("");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this library by [chrisjenx](https://github.com/chrisjenx/ParallaxScrollView), also [nirhart](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll) and [this](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid). It should help

**EDIT1:**

Check this [demo](https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/ViewPagerParallax) also refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013855/android-parallax-effect-and-view-pager) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424088/parallax-effect-in-androids-viewpager).

**EDIT2:**

Check out this **library** [link](https://github.com/xgc1986/ParallaxPagerTransformer) it is for FRAGMENTS

Comment: @user3431980 Check the anser

Comment: @UnityBeginner check the question I mentioned

Comment: @UnityBeginner Check the edit I have conformed that it is for fragments

Comment: @UnityBeginner its library please go and check it out

Comment: @UnityBeginner it's open source for a reason, check it out yourself haha