# How to change pages in Viewpager with overlap of ImageViews?

Tags: android, material-design, materialized-views

how to change pages in Viewpager with overlap(Parallax) of ImageViews like in [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ogqcorp.bgh) ? 
Some day I saw a library, but don't remember where...[image]

Comment: what do u mean by "material Image view"? There're two different layouts, both added to a ViewPager via Adapter. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Budius, not find fault with words, I know that you understood my question. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: @NickUnuchek I literally have no idea what u mean, but sounds like it's something I could help, that's why I (and @piotrek1543) asked you to clarify the question.

Comment: @Budius how to change pages in Viewpager with overlap of ImageViews?

Answer (score 1):

the actual question from the OP is:

> how to change pages in Viewpager with overlap of ImageViews?

That have nothing to do with material design, it's a technique that exist for quite a few years in Android. This technique in general is called "parallax effect": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling

To achieve it in Android is quite simple:

just call [pager.setPageTransformer(false, transformer);](http://public%20void%20setPageTransformer%20(boolean%20reverseDrawingOrder,%20ViewPager.PageTransformer%20transformer))

with an object that implements https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html

and then on the transformer callback you can simple call:

```
public void transformPage (View page, float position) {
      page.findViewById(R.id.imageView).setTranslationX( .. do here some fancy math to move the image ...)
}
```

Other examples can be found on the following links.

[Android Parallax Effect and View Pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013855/android-parallax-effect-and-view-pager)

[Parallax Effect in Android's ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424088/parallax-effect-in-androids-viewpager)

Personally I don't like those link implementation much because they use 3rd party libraries to implement something that can be done literally with a couple of lines of code.