# Android view pager with transition animation

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, shared-element-transition

I am new in android animation. I have refereed so many links but didn't get any proper solution for my case.

So here gif image I want to make same behavior as [this](https://i2.wp.com/myhexaville.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ezgif.com-video-to-gif-22.gif?resize=254%2C452&ssl=1). So please suggest me how can I achieve this ?

**Thanks in advance for help.**

Comment: Please go with https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/viewpager

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424088/parallax-effect-in-androids-viewpager

Comment: Okay I will check it and will respond you if need any help